# Sum over (squares of) Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials, laguerre-polynomials

I'm looking for a closed form of the sum \begin{equation} 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n+k)!} (L_n^k(x))^2 t^n,
\end{equation}
where $L_n^k(x)$ are the Laguerre Polynomials. I have been looking for some time and only found equations that are pretty close, but not exactly what I need (like [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/23/02/)).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Go the wikipedia article for Laguerre polynomials and search for 'Hardy-Hille' formula near the end of it.  Put $\alpha=k$ and $y=x.$